# How to list all files in folders with a wildcard prefix

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I read in [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html) amazon article that you should prefix folder names with a hash, so instead of storing

```
examplebucket/2013-26-05-15-00-00/cust1234234/photo1.jpg
examplebucket/2013-26-05-15-00-00/cust3857422/photo2.jpg
examplebucket/2013-26-05-15-00-00/cust1248473/photo2.jpg
```

you would instead store

```
examplebucket/232a-2013-26-05-15-00-00/cust1234234/photo1.jpg
examplebucket/7b54-2013-26-05-15-00-00/cust3857422/photo2.jpg
examplebucket/921c-2013-26-05-15-00-00/cust1248473/photo2.jpg
```

as this makes the lookup faster internally.

It says you can then send a ListBucket request with a prefix like [0-f][0-f][0-f][0-f]-2013-26-05 if you want to list all the files for that day but i cant figure out how to actually send that wildcard as the prefix.
When I send a ListObjectRequest with the wildcard prefix [0-f][0-f][0-f][0-f]-2013-26-05 I don't find any results, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try `ListObjectsRequest req = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("examplebucket").withPrefix("[0-f][0-f][0-f][0-f]-2013-26-05").withDelimiter("/");`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yeah I tried that and it finds 0 items. If I search for the prefix 232a-2013-26-05-15 then it finds 1 item so it seems like the [0-f] wildcard bit doesn't work as the article seems to suggest it should.

Comment: Please note that the recommendation for using a [using a hash in S3 key names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html) only apply if "your workload in an Amazon S3 bucket routinely exceeds 100 PUT/LIST/DELETE requests per second or more than 300 GET requests per second". Otherwise, there is no need to perform such activities.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yeah unfortunately we will be exceeding that pretty regularly